# Duplicate executions of sql via ibatis

Tags: sql, ibatis

has anyone had any/know of any issues with ibatis submitting several duplicate queries?

we have been seeing (intermittently) the same sql statement being executed up to 5 times.  Originally we thought we were dealing with over zealous click happy users, but we freeze the submit buttons to prevent multiple clicking and we still get this.

I seem to remember reading somewhere that this is a bug in ibatis, but i cant find it again (or maybe i dreamt it, my dreams are often weird).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-369

They say the bug is fixed.

Comment: I dont think so, we didnt get any errors or messages like mentioned here.  We experienced a slowdown on the server which upon investigation by the DBA seemed to be caused by the same prepared statement being executed 4 times simultaneously (each starting within milliseconds of each other).  We've had this several times, first time we assumed users were being click happy so we disabled all buttons upon the first click so they couldnt re-submit the query.